# Hyper V Windows 8.1 Pro won't work. Virtualisation is enabled in BIOS

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

```
I bought Windows 8.1 pro so I could use the Hyper-V Virtualisation. 
I have the correct Hardware

 - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.5GHZ
 - Toshiba C55-A-1N1.

In TaskManager->Performance it says
Virtualisation:       Disabled
Hyper-V support:      Yes

In Turn Windows features on or off Window for Hyper-V it says
Hyper-V                                - ticked with a square tick(Partial tick)
    Hyper-V Management Tools           - ticked
         Hyper-V GUI Management Tools  - ticked 
         Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell
                                       - ticked.
    Hyper-V Platform                   - not able to tick (greyed out)

Hyper-V manager opens but I cannot create a Virtual Machine.

The laptop manufacture Toshiba have assured me that the laptop has the 
capability and it is a Microsoft problem. 
I spent 4+ hours getting bounced around Microsoft tele-operators/technicians 
repeating the same problem to each. I am now waiting on a call back I was 
promised two days ago. I am starting to think there is a known problem that 
no-body want to admit. 

So the question is.
1. Does anyone know how to fix this? or 
2. Is anyone aware of a bug in Windows 8.1 Pro resulting in Hyper-V not working? 

********************************************************************
Continuation after Answer from varun_mc
********************************************************************

This is the message I get from hovering over the greyed out checkbox Hyper-V Platform in Windows  Features.
"Hyper-V cannot be installed: Virtuallisation support is disabled in the firmware."

This could mean Toshiba has turned it off for security or something. 
The output from coreinfo does not mention EPT, see below.
**********************************************************************
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 00000016
HTT         *   Hyperthreading enabled
HYPERVISOR  -   Hypervisor is present
VMX         *   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM         -   Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64         *   Supports 64-bit mode

SMX         -   Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT      -   Supports AMD SKINIT

NX          *   Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP        *   Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP        -   Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB     *   Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE         *   Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT         *   Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE         *   Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36       *   Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE         *   Supports global bit in page tables
SS          *   Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME         *   Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *   Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU         *   Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX         *   Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT      -   Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW       -   Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT    -   Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE         *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3       *   Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a       -   Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES         *   Supports AES extensions
AVX         *   Supports AVX intruction extensions
FMA         *   Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR         *   Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR        *   Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE       *   Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE     *   Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND      *   Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED      -   Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV        *   Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH       *   Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8         *   Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16        *   Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1        *   Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2        *   Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX         -   Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA         -   Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C        *   Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR        *   Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR       -   Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR     *   Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE       *   Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB       *   Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ    *   Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT      *   Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT       *   Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP         *   Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF   *   Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE         -   Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM         -   Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE          *   Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64      *   Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS          *   Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL      *   Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID        *   Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID     *   Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM        *   Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP      *   Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC         *   Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    *   Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *   TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR        *   Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST        *   Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI        *   Implements MSR for power management
TM          *   Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2         *   Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC        *   Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC      -   Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID     -   L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE         *   Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA         *   Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE         *   Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN         -   Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW   *   Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 0000000D (Basic), 80000008 (Extended).

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**--  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
****  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
****  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**--  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**--  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
****  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    3 MB, Assoc  12, LineSize  64
--**  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
****  Group

****************************************************************************  

The intel product description as described on their website
(http://ark.intel.com/products/76348/Intel-Core-i5-4200M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) 
states that ETP is part of the package. See the relevant section below.

Advanced Technologies
Intel® Turbo Boost Technology ‡ 2.0
Intel® vPro Technology ‡    No
Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology ‡     Yes
Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡   Yes
Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) ‡  No
Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT) ‡   Yes
Intel® TSX-NI   Yes
Intel® 64 ‡     Yes
Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology    Yes
Thermal Monitoring Technologies Yes
Intel® Identity Protection Technology ‡ Yes
Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT) ‡   Yes

I guess from now on I will be wanting to see something working before I pay. 
Pretty hard when you are buying over the internet.
```

Answer (score 2):

Hovering over the disabled "Hyper-V Platform" option should give you a hint on why it is disabled:
[image]

Here are few things I would check:

- Make sure that the Hardware-assisted virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
- Make sure Data Execution Prevention (DEP) is enabled in BIOS.
- Make sure your processor is 64 bit and has Second Level Address Translation (SLAT) capabilities. And then confirm SLAT is enabled in BIOS.

You can use Sysinternal's CoreInfo.exe to determine if your machine supports Virtualization and SLAT. Tool can be downloaded from Microsoft Technet site: http://download.sysinternals.com/files/Coreinfo.zip

Run "CoreInfo.exe -v" from elevated command prompt.

```
Coreinfo v3.31 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: ******* 

HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

If you see "-" here, it means your processor does NOT support SLAT; if it is a "*", then it supports SLAT. You should ideally see the output as above before enabling Hyper-V.

Here is a more detailed MSDN article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the thing for resolving this issue in HP laptop for windows 10 

Steps to follow
1> Open task manager and see if virtualization is enable or disable by going to Performance tab.
2> If disable than follow below steps
3> Restart the laptop and on bootup press the Esc key to get the Menu
4> Now Go to Advance menu and inside that go to Device Configuration
5> Scroll down in device configuration you will find Virtualization checkbox so just check that Save changes.
6> Its done...

Cheers!!!
```